# Invalid JSON response using CURL

Tags: curl, playframework-2.0

I have a problem with the play framework 2.1.1 (Java) telling me that I am sending Invalid JSON. There has been a similar /possibly the same issue for the play framework 2.x and 2.1.0, but it was supposed to be resolved in play framework 2.1.1 afaik: See [Invalid JSON in Play Framework 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14804162/invalid-json-in-playframework-2-1-test-post-request)

This is what I am doing in the code, I have tried making it a bit shorter:

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonFactory;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser;
import play.libs.Json;
import play.mvc.BodyParser;

@BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class)
public static Result login() {
    JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();
}
```

When I run:

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"email":"test@test.de","password":"test"}' http://localhost:9000/mobile/login
```

I get the following response:

```
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 1917
...
<p id="detail">
    For request 'POST /mobile/login' [Invalid Json]
</p>
...
```

I have cleaned my project and rerun it several times. When running *play about* I get the following output:

```
[info] Loading project definition from /path/to/project
[info] Set current project to FFPushAlarmPlay (in build file:/path/to)
[info] This is sbt 0.12.2
[info] The current project is {file:/path/to}...
[info] The current project is built against Scala 2.10.0
[info] Available Plugins: play.Project, sbt.PlayProject, com.typesafe.sbteclipse.plugin.EclipsePlugin, com.typesafe.sbtidea.SbtIdeaPlugin
[info] sbt, sbt plugins, and build definitions are using Scala 2.9.2
```

Am I doing something awfully wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated as this is my first Play 2 project!

**Update:** I forgot to mention that I also have an iOS client which automagically builds the JSON using AFNetworking and I also get a Invalid JSON response there. So it doesn't seem to be invalid JSON causing this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I finally got back to looking into this and I found the answer. The problem for me was that there were people with similar issues in Play <2.1.1 and my belief was this was a similar issue, which it wasn't.

I added an unmanaged dependency to the project in the lib directory of my play-project. The library was notnoop java-apns (https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns). Internally, it uses the org.codehaus.jackson-classes which the Play framework also uses. I used version 0.1.5 which is fairly old.

The fix, just remove the apns-library from the lib-directory, remove it from the build-path in eclipse and then in project/target/Build.scala add a managed dependency:

```
"com.notnoop.apns" % "apns" % "0.2.3"
```

Hope this helps whoever runs into similar issues!

Answer (score 17):

There is nothing wrong in your code. Are you using windows command line (`CMD.exe`) to run `curl`? if you are using `CMD.exe` to run `curl`, you must fix the JSON format data you want to passed. I think in Windows, using quote is a bit different from UNIX machine.

The simplest fix is to **avoid using single-quotes** and use double quotes to start and end JSON data, with the **double-quotes** in the JSON data **escaped** (by `\` character), may be a bit tiring but it should works:

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{\"email\":\"test@test.de\",\"password\":\"test\"}" http://localhost:9000/mobile/login
```

or, you can use [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) or *other-UNIX-like-command-line* for windows as alternative command line because its behavior likely as UNIX machine.

Hope it is useful for you friend. :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am using OS X. I just tried your hint about escaping the JSON, but still get "Invalid JSON" as a response. It would have surprised me as I have an iOS client which also gets the same response and uses the AFNetworking lib for the JSON  request. I forgot to mention this in my original post, sorry!

Comment: You can also install Git which includes Git Bash with curl command.

Comment: That "remove single quotes" and "add double quotes" worked like a champ...Thanks...

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem in the CMD and this solved the problem:

```
C:\Windows\System32>curl -v -u login:password -X PUT -d "{\"test\":\"aaa\",\"name\":\"Kowalski\"}" http://127.0.0.1:5984/albums/2340234802938424f7w783
```

P.S. In the program Cygwin this problem does not occur.